# Does @CachePut annotation in springboot replace the existing key with new key in Datagird?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datagrid

Does @CachePut annotation in springboot replace the existing key with new key in data grid?

Answer (score 0):

Action `PUT` is for updating. You can choose updating keep old key or alternating new key.

Read more

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachePut.html#key--
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachePut.html#keyGenerator--